# Can't find MAX value in return from IF formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

So I have this sheet where i want to find the highest number in a range(B7:B17). However i'm only getting zero in my MAX formula(G10). Am I missing something here, or is it not possible to get a return from a IF formula?

Any help is much appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c102q2AVHiw8D3XAOGTLj3dBmP8ooLiLM4wfgnQjhRc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error in your sheet:** The value `8192` and others were treated as `String`.

So, modifying the formulae `=IF($F$2="One","8192","")` to `=IF($F$2="One",8192,0)` corrects the problem. See, sheets below for the result.

**This is your original sheet:**

[image: Original]

**This is the rectified sheet:**

[image: Rectified]

Comment: Ahh Perfect. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)